# why is my R function not printing values?

Tags: r

```
  s <- seq(-10, 6, by = 0.1)

  my.fun = function(s) 
  { 
    n = length(s)
    s = 0
    for(i in 1:n)
    {     
      s = ((s[i]*s[i]*s[i]*s[i])*sin(1/s[i]) +(s[i]*s[i]))/(1+abs((s[i]*s[i]*s[i])))
    }
    s
  }
```

This is my function. I am attempting to compute a sequence of numbers and then use that sequence within the equation. However, It isnt saving the new variable S and the function wont print anything out either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. You're setting `s` to zero in your function
2. The main guts of your function contains `1/s[i]`, so `s` shouldn't contain any zeroes.

Try

```
s <- seq(-10, 6, by = 0.1)
s = s[which(s != 0)] # to drop the zero from the vector

my.fun = function(s)
{
  n = length(s)
  for(i in 1:n) {     
    s[i] = ((s[i]*s[i]*s[i]*s[i])*sin(1/s[i]) + s[i]*s[i]))/(1+abs((s[i]*s[i]*s[i])))
  }
  s
}
my.fun(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant return an output in the definition of a function itself.

Do `my.fun(s)` to return the output for s.

Also make sure to not have 0s while initializing values for s. Since you are doing 1/s at one point, you will return only NaNs.

Comment: The fact that the parameter of the function is `s` and the main variable outside the function is also `s` is fine.  I agree it causes some confusion, but that part of the code is technically correct.